# Dropping Pin On MKMapView With Country/Area Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

In my app i have to adding native map app functionality of 
dropping pin on map after searching any place in search bar and it drop a pin with appropriates zoom level on map .

I am using MkMap view in my app and i drop a pin after long press on map by converting touch point in to Coordinates (by map methods convertingPointToCordites ).and add annotation on map

But now i have to drop pin when user search any place via search bar and have to set zoom lever with pin on map

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
// Place a single pin
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:centerCoordinate];
[annotation setTitle:@"Title"]; //You can set the subtitle too
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```